# Expression for sum of matrix quadratics

Tags: quadratics, matrix-equations

I'm stuck on an algebra problem. For $i=1, \dots, N$, let $Y_i \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times p}$, and $\hat{M} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N Y_i$ be the matrix of the element-wise averages. Suppose $V \in \mathbb{S}_+^r$ is a positive definite $r \times r$ matrix.

I'm dealing with the sum of the quadratic terms:

$$ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N (Y_i - \hat{M})'V^{-1}(Y_i - \hat{M}), $$
and am curious if its possible to rewrite this sum in terms of $N-1$ summands. For example, in the case that $N = 2$, its clear that $$ \hat{M} = \frac{1}{2}Y_1 + \frac{1}{2}Y_2,$$
and consequently
$$ (Y_1 - \hat{M}) = \frac{1}{2}Y_1 - \frac{1}{2}Y_2 = -(Y_2 - \hat{M}), $$ so that we can write the sum
$$ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^2 (Y_i - \hat{M})'V^{-1}(Y_i - \hat{M}) = (\frac{1}{2}Y_1 - \frac{1}{2}Y_2)'V^{-1}(\frac{1}{2}Y_1 - \frac{1}{2}Y_2).$$

Is there a generalization of this to arbitrary $N$?

Comment: We can always write $Y_i - \hat M = \frac{N-1}{N}Y_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^N Y_j$, but this is probably not the formulation we are looking for, is it?

Comment: Correct -- but I'm not sure this solves the question at hand. Fundamentally, the point is that only $N−1$
of the $Y_i$ can vary if we know $\hat{M}$